# Why does this return -1 instead of 201?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been experimenting with files in Python. I made three:

- file number 1 has `156` in it
- file number 2 has `45` in it
- file op has `++&/**` in it because I want to see if you can add through a file

```
FilePath_file1 = r'D:\python_CSV\Number1.txt'
FilePath_file2 = r'D:\python_CSV\Number2.txt'
FilePath_fileOP = r'D:\python_CSV\Op.txt'

File1 = open(FilePath_file1,'r')
File2 = open(FilePath_file2,'r')
FileOp = open(FilePath_fileOP,'r')


Number1 = File1.readline()
Number2 = File2.readline()
OpCommand = FileOp.readline()

x = int(Number1)
y = int(Number2)

z = -1
if OpCommand == '+':
    z = x + y

print('The result is:- ',z)
```

The code keeps returning -1 instead of 201, which is what the answer should be. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

When you read in your value for `OpCommand` it is the whole line `++&/**`, so matching against the single character `+` will return `false`. Hence `z` is never modified. Even if you have the operator characters on separate lines, `readline()` includes the newline character, so you need to either remove it or just use `OpCommand[0]` to match. Replace

```
if OpCommand == '+':
```

with

```
if OpCommand[0] == '+':
```

Comment: so how would u suggest i fix it ?

Comment: Hi. I answered your first question 'why' and then your second 'how to fix it'. I hope it helped. Fancy returning the favour by accepting the answer?